# How to pass post parameter from laravel route to axios in vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I need to pass those parameters data_from and data_to to the axios call but it's not working. I'm doing something wrong? The response is undefined.

Controller:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller 
    {
        public function apiPaymentByUserId(Request $request) { 
    
    
            $data_from = $request -> data_from;
            $data_to = $request -> data_to;
    
            $payments = DB::table("casefiles, payments")
                ->select("payments.*")
                ->where("casefiles.id", "=", 'payments.casefile_id')
                ->where("casefiles.user_id", "=", Auth::id())
                ->where("payments.created_at", ">=", $data_from)
                ->where("payments.updated_at", "<=", $data_to)
                ->get();
    
                
                return response()->json([ 
                    'success' => true, 
                    'response' => $payments 
                ]);
        
        }
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/payments', 'Api\PaymentController@apiPaymentByUserId');
```

Axios call with vue js:

```
axios.post('/payments', {
    
    params: {

        data_from: this.data_from,
        data_to: this.data_to

    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your axios code is

```
axios.post('/payments', {
    
    params: {

        data_from: this.data_from,
        data_to: this.data_to

    }
})
```

if you `dd($request->all())` in controller you will get below output

```
array:1 [
  "params" => array:2 [
    "data_from" => ""
    "data_to" => ""
  ]
]
```

so to fetch individual like below

```
$request->params['data_from']
```

So better pass data  in axios like below

```
axios.post('/payments', {

        data_from: this.data_from,
        data_to: this.data_to
})
```

so you can fetch

```
$request->data_from
```

Ref: https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 1):

Change that

```
            $data_from = $request -> $data_from;
            $data_to = $request -> $data_to;
```

for this

```
            $data_from = $request->data_from;
            $data_to = $request->data_to;
```

Answer (score 0):

try accessing route parameters like this `$data_from = $request->data_from;`